# Getting both route data and queryaparams of the activatedRoute

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

I am using the following code to retrieve `data` from `activatedroute`

```
this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
        .map(route => {
            while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
            return route;
        })
        .filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary')
        .mergeMap(route => route.data)
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.publicRoute = res["publicRoute"] || false;                
        });
```

I am using an almost identical snippet to retrieve `queryPrams` from the same route.

```
this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
        .map(route => {
            while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
            return route;
        })
        .filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary')
        .mergeMap(route => route.queryParams)
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.internaltoken= res["internaltoken"] || false;                
        });
```

I am interested to see if there is a way to use just one snippet to subscribe to both. I am aware of `Observable.combineLatest` but I can't figure out how to fit into the above pipeline.

Comment: Can you be more specific and share the order snippet as well.

Comment: Why don't you just map to `route` and then assign both `this.publicRoute` and `this.internalToken` inside a single `subscribe` function?

Comment: Because `data` and `queryParams` are observables, hence the `mergeMap`. Or i am not understanding what you are suggesting. Please provide code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
const route$ = this.router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .mapTo(this.route)
  .map(route => {
    while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild
    return route
  })
  .filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary')

const latest$ = route$
  .switchMap(route => route.data)
  .combineLatest(route$.switchMap(route => route.queryParams))
  .subscribe(([data, queryParams]) => {
    /* ... */
  })
```

Couple things to notice:

1. I reuse as much as possible. You essentially always go to the filtered route and from there the desired data forks. So there is nothing easier than storing that filter route stream - `route$` - to separate variable and reusing that in the second `latest$` stream with `combineLatest` in particular.
2. Instead of `mergeMap` I used `switchMap`, with which I make sure only subscriptions to the `data` and `queryParams` of the latest route will be made. In this case an may not be needed, but I see it as more appropriate generally. I also used `mapTo` on the line 3 just to simplify things even more.

PS If you plan update to Angular 6 in the future, I suggest you have a look at the [`pipe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) operator.